# My Greasemonkey script stopped working after something updated

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, cdata, e4x, scriptish

I had made a Greasemonkey script for *StumbleUpon*, and it worked. But suddenly, maybe after a Mozilla or Scriptish update, it stopped working on all protocols.

Please review [my script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/126614) for a mistake.  I am a novice in scripting

Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            [udit]add stumblethru image-flip button[w/o container] on all websites
// @namespace       testing-for-that-script
// @description     
// @include         http://facebook.com/*
// @include         http://*
// @include         https://*
// @include         *
// @exclude         file:///*
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.top != window.self)  //don't run on frames or iframes
{
    //Optional: GM_log ('In frame');
    return;
}

/*--- Create a button in a container div.  It will be styled and positioned with CSS.
*/
var zNode       = document.createElement ('input');
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'suButton');
zNode.setAttribute( 'type', 'image' );
zNode.setAttribute( 'src', 'http://www.creativeadornments.com/nephco/doraemon/icons/doraemon_18a.gif' );
document.body.appendChild (zNode);

function tiddu1()
{
document.getElementById("suButton").src ="http://www.creativeadornments.com/nephco/doraemon/icons/doraemon_07.gif";
}

function tiddu2()
{
document.getElementById("suButton").src ="http://www.creativeadornments.com/nephco/doraemon/icons/doraemon_18a.gif";
}

function tiddu3()
{
document.getElementById("suButton").src ="http://www.creativeadornments.com/nephco/doraemon/icons/dorami_01a.gif";
}

function tiddu4()
{
document.getElementById("suButton").src ="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSI_hx0nLvnO-Em6elAxyMnoBFGw8IMD3Yrpep4XY2I51GylSRf3jHiabAyiw";
}

//--- Activate the newly added button and add rollover image handling.
var zNode = document.getElementById ("suButton");
zNode.addEventListener ("click",        ButtonClickAction,  true);
zNode.addEventListener ("mouseover",    tiddu1,          true);
zNode.addEventListener ("mouseout",     tiddu2,           true);
zNode.addEventListener ("mousedown",     tiddu3,           true);
zNode.addEventListener ("click",     tiddu4,           true);

function ButtonClickAction (zEvent)
{
    //--- For our dummy action, we'll just add a line of text to the top of the screen.
    var button  = document.createElement ('a');
    location.href='http://www.stumbleupon.com/to/stumble/stumblethru:'+location.href.replace("http://","").replace("https://","").replace("ftp://","").split('/',4)[0];
}

//--- Style our newly added elements using CSS.
GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    #suButton {
        position:               fixed;
        bottom:                 0px;
        left:                   0px;
        margin:                 0px 0px 50px 0px;
        opacity:                0.8;
        cursor:                 url(C:\buttercup_06.cur),url(http://www.creativeadornments.com/nephco/powerpuffgirls/cursors/ppg_01anim.gif),url(myBall.cur),pointer;
        border:                 0px outset red;
        z-index:                222;
        padding:                5px 5px;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firefox version 17, [Firefox dropped support for E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X).  E4X is what allowed us to use that `(<><![CDATA[ ... ]]></>).toString ()` construct to make easy, robust, multi-line strings.

Now that E4X is no longer supported, we must refactor every bit of code that used `CDATA`, to use the javascript string escape (`\`).  So you need to change that `GM_addStyle` call to:

```
GM_addStyle ( "                                             \
    #suButton {                                             \
        position:       fixed;                              \
        bottom:         0px;                                \
        left:           0px;                                \
        margin:         0px 0px 50px 0px;                   \
        opacity:        0.8;                                \
        cursor:         url(C:\buttercup_06.cur),url(http://www.creativeadornments.com/nephco/powerpuffgirls/cursors/ppg_01anim.gif),url(myBall.cur),pointer; \
        border:         0px outset red;                     \
        z-index:        222;                                \
        padding:        5px 5px;                            \
    }                                                       \
" );
```

Taking care with how you mix `'` and `"` quotes.

---

---

Also, since you are using `GM_addStyle`, add [`// @grant GM_addStyle`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) to your script's metadata block so that the script continues to work with future versions of Greasemonkey and Scriptish.

Comment: that was most helpful and working buddy ! a great relax . there is a little bit of a problem in same sort of script , i try to modify it according to the solution but it ain't work . that bit of script is n next comment , please review .sorry for my bad english skills or site ettiquete that u have to edit my question .

Comment: i couldn't put the bit of script in comment , so i updated/edited the question to insert that script.

Comment: As a courtesy, and to avoid confusion, whenever an answer works for the question as asked, but you have a new wrinkle that wasn't covered in the original question, for which the answer doesn't work, ask it in a comment (if it's trivial enough) or open a new question and link back to the original.  In this case, linking to a pastebin (from your comment) would have been enough, but editing the question is a little confusing. All that said... ...

Comment: Refer to the bit about `Taking care with how you mix ' and " quotes`.   The whole `GM_addStyle` call is wrapped in double-quotes (`"`), but double-quotes are used again inside the string!  To fix this, change all internal, double-quotes to single quotes. So, in this case, `"Times New Roman"` should be changed to `'Times New Roman'`.